# Google Play Leaderboard scores are not shown in-app

Tags: android

I developed an android game.I used Google Play Leaderboard in my game.Leaderboard was working correctly when I try the game with usb cable on Android Studio,all scores saved.Then I published my game from play store, I downloaded the game with different phone and there was a problem.

My problem is the leaderboard scores are'nt shown in app. The leaderboard interface comes up but says "No leaderboards for this game".Gamer scores do not appear.

Any ideas?What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the correct App Certificate? I had issues when using the Upload Certificate instead of the App Certificate.
The upload one worked fine for development, but not in the Play Store.

Also, I saw somewhere that it can take up to 24hrs before scores are added to be viewed by everyone.

Another thing: did you add 'a' leaderboard or a specific one with an ID?
If with an ID, try to add just a leaderboard instead and see if that works.